# ERROR in node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(7800,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js, typescript-typings

I'm getting the following error when in my Angular 6 app when running `ng serve`

```
   ERROR in node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(7800,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(7801,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
node_modules/@types/three/three-vrcontrols.d.ts(15,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
node_modules/@types/three/three-vreffect.d.ts(20,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
```

The below are my dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.5",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
"@ng-toolkit/serverless": "^1.1.41",
"@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.41-beta.110",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
"@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.13",
"@types/greensock": "^1.15.32",
"@types/three": "^0.92.17",
"aws-serverless-express": "^3.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"cors": "~2.8.4",
"cp-cli": "^1.1.0",
"gsap": "^2.0.1",
"hamburgers": "^0.9.3",
"load-google-maps-api": "^1.3.2",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"three": "^0.87.1",
"ts-loader": "4.2.0",
"webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
```

This used to run without any issues, but I can't work out what has changed, running `npm install` doesn't change anything. If I copy an old version of `node_modules` it compiles without any issue, which makes me think it has to be a package issue rather than a Typescript config?

Comment: Related: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/missing-types-when-importing-three-js-for-ionic/4331

Answer (score 1):

`VRDisplay` is defined in the `dom` standard library in TypeScript 2.8 and newer.  Check your TypeScript version.  It's possible that your old `node_modules` directory works if it has a version of `@types/three` from before the reference to `VRDisplay` was added.